# Passing multiple PHP variables to shell_exec()?

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I am calling test.sh from PHP using shell_exec method.

```
$my_url="http://www.somesite.com/";
$my_refer="http://www.somesite.com/";
$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php $my_url $my_refer');
```

However, the command line script says it only received 1 argument: the /tmp/my_script.php

When i change the call to:

Code:

```
$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php {$my_url} {$my_refer}');
```

It says it received 3 arguments but the argv[1] and argv[2] are empty.

When i change the call to:

Code:

```
$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php "http://www.somesite.com/" "http://www.somesite.com/"');
```

The script finally receives all 3 arguments as intended.

Do you always have to send just quoted text with the script and are not allowed to send a variable like $var? Or is there some special way you have to send a $var?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is need to send the arguments with quota so you should use it like:

```
$page = shell_exec("/tmp/my_script.php '".$my_url."' '".$my_refer."'");
```

Comment: yeah how do you grab those parameters in the "/tmp/my_script.php" ?

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez-Ocampo Try `print_r($_POST);` to get the parameters.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez-Ocampo **print_r($_SERVER['argv']));**

Comment: This will absolutely not work. Variables are not interpolated in single quoted strings.

Comment: @miken32 Perhaps you have not seen braces which is used to manipulate the variables.

Comment: Those are also not interpreted in single quoted strings.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 28):

Change

`$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php $my_url $my_refer');`

to

`$page = shell_exec("/tmp/my_script.php $my_url $my_refer");`

OR

`$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php "'.$my_url.'" "'.$my_refer.'"');`

Also make sure to use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on both your values.

Example:

```
$my_url=escapeshellarg($my_url);
$my_refer=escapeshellarg($my_refer);
```

Comment: PHP will only parse `$` variables wrapped around double quotes (`"`).

Comment: also make sure you sanatize with escapseshellarg

Comment: See the docs for the differences between single- and double-quoted strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I don't think it would help. He`d better embed quotes inside.

Comment: And what about spaces in filenames?

Answer (score 9):

Variables won't interpolate inside of a single quoted string. Also you should make sure the your arguments are properly escaped.

```
 $page = shell_exec('/tmp/myscript.php '.escapeshellarg($my_url).' '.escapeshellarg($my_refer));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php $my_url $my_refer');
```

to

```
$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php "'.$my_url.'" "'.$my_refer.'"');
```

Then you code will tolerate spaces in filename.

Comment: Yes, I do intentionally. My real mistake was, that I forgot to take out `$my_url` and `$my_refer` out of string.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) helpful here:

```
$my_url="http://www.somesite.com/";
$my_refer="http://www.somesite.com/";
$page = shell_exec(sprintf('/tmp/my_script.php "%s" "%s"', $my_url, $my_refer));
```

You should definitely use [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) as recommended in the other answers if you're not the one supplying the input.

Answer (score 2):

I had difficulty with this so thought I'd share my code snippet.

**Before**

```
$output = shell_exec("/var/www/sites/blah/html/blahscript.sh 2>&1 $host $command");
```

**After**

```
$output = shell_exec("/var/www/sites/blah/html/blahscript.sh 2>&1 $host {$command}");
```

Adding the `{}` brackets is what fixed it for me.

Also, to confirm `escapeshellarg` is also needed.

```
$host=escapeshellarg($host);
$command=escapeshellarg($command);
```

Except script also needed:

```
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set command [lindex $argv 1]
```