# python sys.argv[1] list index out of range

Tags: php, python

I want to send data with php and get with python. But shell_exec cannot send parameter. I cannot understand where is the problem. [this does not fix my error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932113/passing-variables-to-shell-exec)

this is my php file

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["username"])){
        $nick = $_POST["username"];
    echo $nick;//prints ozan to webpage
  $res = shell_exec("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\wamp\www\MLWebsite\website\new.py '".$nick."'");
        echo $res;
    }
    ?>
```

new.py

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("""
  <TITLE></TITLE>
  <H1></H1>
"""
)

import pymysql.cursors
import sys
import json
import urllib2, urllib
import requests

x = sys.argv[1]
print x
```

Error

> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\wamp\www\MLWebsite\website\new.py", line 15, in 
>       x = sys.argv[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932113/passing-variables-to-shell-exec) IndexError: list index out of range

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: that's because `$nick` is empty

Comment: No I can print $nick in php file. I tried that. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Have you tried just printing `sys.argv` and seeing what's in it?

Comment: I try that after you said. The result is that `'C:\\wamp\\www\\MLWebsite\\website\\new.py']` @ubadub

Comment: Did you try to call command from cmd? Does it work then?

Comment: Yea, that means `$nick` is definitely empty. Can you try `echo`ing `$nick$ in the PHP just to make sure?

Comment: I do not know how can I call command from cmd @Wolen

Comment: Open windows cmd and paste ```C:\Python27\python.exe C:\wamp\www\MLWebsite\website\new.py 'test'```

Comment: WhenI write echo `$nick` to php, I  see my nickname in webpage. It is not empty in php file but I cannot pass it to python I think. @ubadub

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/5GZrDM.png I think it is not important error :S @Wolen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Variables to shell\_exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932113/passing-variables-to-shell-exec)

Comment: I try but `sys.argv` is always equal to  `['C:\\wamp\\www\\MLWebsite\\website\\new.py']` @ubadub

Comment: @ozan see the question I linked to. Your question is a duplicate.

Comment: I tried, but, I got same result in `sys.argv`

Comment: Should I install any python package? Or I am using local WAMP SERVER and Is it possible because of that?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$res = shell_exec('C:\Python27\python.exe C:\wamp\www\MLWebsite\website\new.py ' . $nick);
```