# how to pass arguments in execution file using php

Tags: php

When I supply arguments to my application it doesn't run. It does without arguments.

```
shell_exec('C:\Program Files\yrdy\yrdsy\yrdy\yr5dr.exe"/"  user=000"," -pw=123 ');
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple PHP variables to shell\_exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932113/passing-multiple-php-variables-to-shell-exec)

Answer (score 0):

please in the future give us more details of you code.

To answer your question, you have to send the arguments with quota

for exemple :

```php
$user=000;
$pw="-pw=123";
shell_exec('C:\Program Files\yrdy\yrdsy\yrdy\yr5dr.exe"/'" .$user."' '" .$pw."'");
```

Tell us if it helps you.

More details here : [Passing multiple PHP variables to shell_exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932113/passing-multiple-php-variables-to-shell-exec)

Comment: its not working any other solution in command my exe with aruguments is working  but passing with php is not working

Comment: Did you try to debug to check where you code stop running ?

Comment: i didn't know how to bug.. i tried in command it work properly